# Crystal chandelier photography

Tags: lighting

How can I take a perfect picture from a crystal chandelier?
whould someone explain all tips about this kind of photography?

Comment: _From_, or _of_? There's a large difference in the amount of acrobatic skill required. :)

Comment: ...and assuming you mean *"How can I take a perfect picture **of** a crystal chandelier"* the next thing you may want to clarify is: are you wanting to take a picture of a room *with a chandelier in it*, or are you wanting to take a picture of *just a chandelier*?

Comment: How can I vote this as one of the most obscure questions ever?

Comment: On vanilla stackoverflow the question back would be: What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

As a start, I would imagine you'll want a large main light source, bounced off a wall or the ceiling to evenly light the chandelier and avoid harsh shadows.  Then a smaller light source in the vicinity of the camera to provide specular highlights.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a broader answer than you were asking for, but my go-to reference is this book: [Light: Science And Magic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Light-Science-Introduction-Photographic-Lighting/dp/0240808193/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1306841657&sr=1-1) (Amazon.co.uk link).

Here's the link on [Amazon.com](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240808193)

I've recently finished it, and although it is a hard read (well written by very technical), it was well worth it.  It explains why certain lighting schemes work for lighting different kinds of surfaces with different kinds of reflections.

I think it would equip you with some depth of understanding about not just *how* to light a chandelier but *why* that it the way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It's easier to photograph a sunlit chandelier because of the wide angles of refraction. The direct sun does not need to be part of the picture. With a lighted halogen lamp you have no choice. But Halogen lamps are far better than straight incandescent bulbs. That's just a useful tip.